# Python equivalent of C# ADAL AuthenticationContext.AcquireToken

Tags: c#, python, adal

I am following a [tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/developer/walkthrough-push-data-get-token) for authenticating via AAD for the Power BI REST API.

The tutorial uses C# and ADAL. It acquires a token by,

```
AuthenticationContext authContext = new AuthenticationContext(authorityUri);
string token = authContext.AcquireToken(resourceUri, clientID, new Uri(redirectUri)).AccessToken;
```

I would prefer to use Python and so am trying to use the [ADAL library for Python](https://github.com/AzureAD/azure-activedirectory-library-for-python).

I can get an authentication context via,

```
context = adal.AuthenticationContext(authority_url)
```

but I cannot find the equivalent Python ADAL function for AcquireToken. The nearest option seems to be `context.acquire_token` but this requires me to supply a `user_id` arg which the C# version does not (it also does not accept a redirect URI arg).

How do I get the same behaviour in Python as in the tutorial's C# code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(I mean to put this as a comment to the conversation in [Marcus's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50087382/728675), but it is getting too long to fit there)

Thanks Marcus for pointing to a working sample and that blog post. However it would be worth to point out that:

- There is a huge conceptual difference between authenticating as an app and authenticating as an end user. They are not interchangable. It seems @JamesElderfield wants to authenticate an end user interactively, in such case the `acquire_token_with_client_credentials(...)` is not the droid you are looking for.
- That C# `authContext.AcquireToken(resourceUri, clientID, new Uri(redirectUri))` equivalent is roughly the `acquire_token_with_authorization_code(...)` in ADAL Python, however <strike>it is true that it is currently not yet</strike> , although it is [already supported](https://github.com/AzureAD/azure-activedirectory-library-for-python/issues/140) in ADAL Python for native app (a.k.a. public client), it would require the app developer to implement their own logic to start up an HTTP server to catch the redirected auth code.
- If the option above sounds too complicated for you, that leaves you the option of using [Device Code flow](https://github.com/AzureAD/azure-activedirectory-library-for-python/blob/1.2.1/sample/device_code_sample.py), which is correctly suggested by [@abhidnya 's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50123353/728675).

Answer (score 4):

The usage of acquire token function is little different in ADAL Python. In ADAL Python you will have to know which authentication flow you want to follow and then use the appropriate acquire token call. You can find the different authentication flows relevant for an application type and topology in this [Azure AD article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-authentication-scenarios#application-types-and-scenarios) and usage of the different acquire token calls for python in these [samples](https://github.com/AzureAD/azure-activedirectory-library-for-python/tree/dev/sample)

From the scenario you mentioned above, you can use this [auth code flow](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-python-webapp-graphapi)  sample. It needs a client secret but the token is granted after the user signs in interactively.

If you still want an interactive flow without providing a client secret, you can refer to the [device code flow](https://github.com/AzureAD/azure-activedirectory-library-for-python/blob/dev/sample/device_code_sample.py) sample. However, device code flow is mostly used for text-only devices which do not have an interactive web interface of its own. The user can use another device with an interactive web interface to do the sign in.

Answer (score 0):

I got it working by following the example in the "Acquire token with client creds" section in the [ADAL lib GitHub page](https://github.com/AzureAD/azure-activedirectory-library-for-python#acquire-token-with-client-credentials).

```
import adal
...
context = adal.AuthenticationContext("your_authority_uri")
token = context.acquire_token_with_client_credentials("your_resource_uri", _client_id, _client_secret)
```

A few samples [here](https://github.com/AzureAD/azure-activedirectory-library-for-python/tree/dev/sample).

Does that work for you?

Comment: This requires the use of a client secret, which is not something the C# version requires. In the C# example a web browser pops up and requests your username + password to authenticate.

Comment: I see, so what you want is interactive auth... according to this link [here](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/resources/samples/data-lake-analytics-python-auth-options/), this might not be supported at the moment - see under Authenticate interactively...: "This option is used when you want to have a browser popup appear when the user signs in to your application, showing an AAD login form. (…) This is not supported yet."

Comment: Your reading skills seem to beat mine, if you submit that explanation as an answer I'll accept it

Comment: Please see my comments [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50162786/728675)